# How to get id with select distinct query

Tags: mysql

I have in mysql table:

> id | title | location | price

There are duplicates in table. For getting all unique I use

> SELECT DISTINCT title, location, price

Is it possible to get an ids of all unique rows utilizing only sql query? No matter which id will with row (first, second or last).
Thanks for help

Comment: Once you include the `id`, if those values are different then you're no longer able to rely on the default behavior of `DISTINCT`.  You would need to define your own logic of what "distinct" means.  Essentially it sounds like you have bad data.  Instead of trying to effectively ignore it, correct it.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if title, location, price fields have duplicate records.

then following query will be best

```
select id from tablel1 group by title, location, price
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped

Comment: why is my answer is down, it is correct answer , you can test my query

Comment: I didn't push down. I could not do this yet. I marked your answer as right

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
select distinct id, title, location
from table_name
```

Comment: Please post table with data and expected output